# Floating-point in Python vs Mathematica

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, wolfram-mathematica

Given the limited hardware and its memory we encounter float-point problem. My questions is, how come in Python: `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3` returns  `False` while Mathematica returns it `True`?

How did Wolfram guys managed it to work and can Python developers implement their solution?

Comment: If you need exact floating-point precision in Python, check out the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module.

Comment: It's the other way around. Wolfram products approximates the result. Python is doing the right thing. And you shouldn't do this type of checks or make it explicit for example see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485/

Comment: Thank you for your informative comments.

Comment: We can debate whats "right". Mathematica understands precision and correctly reports that they are equal within numerical precision.  If you want to check to-the-last-bit equality in mathematica you could do something like `RealDigits[.1 + .1 + .1, 2] == RealDigits[.3, 2] -> False`

Comment: @agentp You have made it sound like a good idea (“understands precision and correctly reports”—I don't think it does), so now I have to post the link to [How Futile are Mindless Assessments of Roundoff in Floating-Point Computation ?](https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Mindless.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Wolfram documentation at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html

> Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits).

So it's just a different rule for `==` comparisons.

Comment: Thank you very much Alan. That answers it, but I cannot vote yet due to insufficient reputations.

Comment: For your own questions, you should accept an appropriate answer, rather than voting for it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work